# crtp parent access to sister class

Tags: c++, inheritance, crtp

i have a class named base. this class is inaccessable(i mean the sourcecode) since it is a 3rd party class. this class has a method that i want to access from a (parent)sister (let's say uncle) class.

```cpp
class base {
public:
  void do_something() {
    std::cout << "base1::do_something" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

i have another parent class which is made by using [crtp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to access the members of the child class:

```
template<typename crtpT>
class crtp {
public:
  void foo() {
    std::cout << "crtp::foo" << std::endl;
    static_cast<crtpT*>(this)->bar();

    //static_cast<crtpT::base_type*>(this)->do_something();
    // how do i access base::bar
  }
};
```

and last, a child class which inherits from both:

```
template<typename baseT>
class child : public baseT, public crtp<child<baseT> > {
public:
  typedef baseT base_type;

  void bar() {
    std::cout << "child::bar" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  child<base> ch;
  ch.do_something();
  ch.foo();
  ch.bar();
  return 0;
}
```

now my problem is, i need to access `do_something` from my **crtp**-class. is this even possible?

a static_cast won't work. i think while generating the crtp class the compiler do not know anything about the base class. crtp class **have to be** a parent of class child, since a lot other classes deriving from it. otherwise i may use a [delegation to sister-class](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/mi-delegate-to-sister.html).

---

### edit:

i may could do a second bar method inside my child, but this isn't really nice because i have to write wrapper for all the methods from the **base** class.

```
template<typename baseT>
class child : public baseT, public crtp<child<baseT> > {

public:
  typedef baseT base_type;

  void bar() {
    std::cout << "child::bar" << std::endl;
  }

  void bar2() {
    base_type::do_something();
  }
};
```

and call:

```
static_cast<crtpT*>(this)->bar2();
```

Comment: Have you tried 2 `static_cast`s? From `crtp` to `child` to `base`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static_cast`: [expr.static.cast]/11

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B,” where B is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 D,” where D is a class derived from B [...]

Therefore, you need to convert from `crtp<...>*` to the child class `child*` and then you can even use an implicit cast to `base`, e.g.

```
crtpT::base_type* p = static_cast<crtpT*>(this);
```